# Working with key-value pairs in two dictionaries (Python)

Tags: python

Say I have two dictionaries:

```
score={"hello": 5, "goodbye": 1, "how are you": 7}
word_count = {"hello": 1, "goodbye": 1, "how are you": 3}
```

And an input:

```
text=input("Enter your text here: ")
text_list = text.split(" ")
```

And, if the key is in the input, I want to print the value. How do I do this (using a for loop inside a for loop prints it twice)?
My output looks like this:

```
for sentence, rating in score:
   for sent, rate in word_count:
       number = int(rating) / (int(rate) - len(text_list))
       print(number)
```

Comment: can you provide sample input and output?

Comment: I have just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

if the dictionaries are same length you can loop for one dic

```py
score      = {"hello": 5, "goodbye": 1, "how are you": 7}
word_count = {"hello": 1, "goodbye": 1, "how are you": 3}

text       = input("Enter your text here: ")
if text in score:
  score[text] # do whatever with it
  word_count[text] # do whatever with it
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the keys in score and word_count are the same.

If the key is in the input, print the value :

```
score      = {"hello": 5, "goodbye": 1, "how are you": 7}
word_count = {"hello": 1, "goodbye": 1, "how are you": 3}
input_text = input("Enter your text here: ")

size = len(input_text.split(" "))
for key in score:
    if key in input_text:
        rating = score[key]
        rate  = word_count[key]
        print(f'{key:<12} : {rating / rate - size:.2f}')
```

input  :
`hello how are you I am fine goodbye`

output :

```
hello        : -3.00  # 5 / 1 - 8
goodbye      : -7.00  # 1 / 1 - 8
how are you  : -5.67  # 7 / 3 - 8
```